# credentials on google cloud translate services

Tags: python, authentication, credentials, google-translate, google-translation-api

I'm making a desktop application using python, this application needs to get get to google cloud translation service.

On my computer I use the Application Default Credentials (ADC) to access the service, but for other users (that I'll be giving the program to use) I don't want to give them my gmail account or forcing them to use google cloud services.

So, I was trying to use either the API key or the service account access, but I failed to find the way to do that in google's documentation.

**How can I make the program without using my account login?**

note: I'm mid level in python, not always I can understand everything in a written code.

---

What I did:

I installed the required headers/modules using pip, and tried to use the python functions that google provides for API key and service account ... I was expecting the application to connect using the given API key to my account (used for billing) but without using my username and password.

obviously I failed to do so.